# PHP help with using variable inside code

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have this line of code: `<?php global $bp; query_posts( 'author=$bp->displayed_user->id' ); if (have_posts()) : ?>` but it doesn't work as expected. Probably because it's not grabbing the `$bp->displayed_user->id` part correctly. How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because it's treating the `'author=$bp->displayed_user->id'` as a string rather than inlining the contents of the variable. (This is the main difference between using single and double quotes. Have a read of the PHP [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) manual page for more information.)

To fix this, try either:

```
query_posts('author=' . $bp->displayed_user->id);
```

or

```
query_posts("author={$bp->displayed_user->id}");
```

That said, I'd *personally* recommend the first approach, as it's more explicit what's going on.

Comment: Second solution does not work. In this case curly brackets are necessary.

Comment: @Tomik Good point - I've amended by answer. Thanks for the heads-up. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php global $bp; query_posts( 'author=' . $bp->displayed_user->id ); if (have_posts()) : ?>
```

In single quoted strings variables will not be expanded. See documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I'm not following. How would I pass the id to the author bit then?

Comment: Dot concatenates two strings - 'author=' and $bp->displayed_user->id resulting in something like 'author=5'.

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes makes PHP do not fetch the variable value.
Instead of using single quotes you can use double quotes:

```
<?php 
    global $bp; 
    query_posts( "author={$bp->displayed_user->id}" ); if (have_posts()) : 
?>
```

Or this way (I thik that is better):

```
<?php 
    global $bp; 
    query_posts( 'author=' . $bp->displayed_user->id ); if (have_posts()) :  
?>
```

Comment: Note that your first solution doesn't work. "$a->b" works but "$a->b->c" does not work. Not sure why.